# Can I map a drive to a NAS (linux based) from my Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, nas, storage

I want to buy an NAS to use as backup and to store pictures.  I want to be able to create disk images, through Acronis, and store them there as well.  Can I map a drive to the NAS in Windows 7 and read and write directly to it?  If not any suggestions on what to use for my purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not seeing any problem to map a drive for a NAS share for R/W, just make sure the NFS is Windows-certified (the commons problems are with old ones, like using deprecated encryption techniques or stuffs alike ...)

Comment: Or, for the non-Windows geeks, SAMBA-enabled.

Comment: @Hello71 does Samba enabled let me map a drive though?

Comment: Samba (or the linux implementation of SMB (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)) is the system Windows uses to share files over the network. E.g., if it supports Samba, it should be natively accessible in windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Synology DS407+ (Linux based NAS) and have had no problem mapping drives in Windows 7.  SAMBA is indeed enabled. Good luck!

Comment: I have a Thecus N7700, and it works fine in W7 and XP as well.